# How to Use/Start Laravel Services in "ConfigureLogging" Overridden File?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have to create separate log files for the companies Laravel 5. I have already done this in Laravel by just putting my logic in `global.php` file. This makes it easy to trace the errors if a specific company admin puts a complaint. Anyway, in Laravel 5 the whole structure is changed for the framework.

I've tried to override `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging` class in `app/bootstrap` directory. Every thing is going fine but when I try to get `Company::find($id);`, which I needed there, Laravel thrown error `Call to a member function connection() on null` which means I'm trying to use Laravel services before they get started.

So, I used `mysqli` PHP library to get company name. Now it's working fine. But somehow I want to use `Eloquent` instead of `mysqli`. But don't know how can I use `Eloquent` in other words starting Laravel Services in such scenarios.

Here is my code:

```
$companyId = isset($_COOKIE['companyId'])?$_COOKIE['companyId']:null;

if(!(is_null($companyId))){
    $today = date('d-m-Y');
    if(!file_exists(storage_path().'/logs/'.$today)){
        // I've created the Filesystem instance as File Facade was not working here.
        $file = new Filesystem;
        $file->makeDirectory(storage_path(). '/logs/' . $today, 0777);
    } // No problem till here

    // I need to get company name from db and want to use the following two lines But...
    $company = Company::find($id);  
    $companyName = str_replace(' ', '_', $company->name).'_'.$companyId;
    // ... as laravel services are not yet started I have to use the  following mysqli block (13 lines) from mysqli_connect() to mysqli_close()

    // ENDING MYSQLI BLOCK
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'myDb', '3306');
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        mysqli_query($link, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
        $sql = 'SELECT name FROM companies WHERE id='.$companyId;
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $companyName = $row['name'];
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    // ENDING MYSQLI BLOCK

    $log->useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$today.'/'.$companyName.'.log', $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5));
}elseif(is_null($companyId)){
    $log->useDailyFiles(storagePath().'/logs/laravel.log', $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5));
}
```

Should I change Logging behavior in any other way i.e. using `Service Providers` or something else? Please help me in this regard.